# Xcode 9.2 is not showing Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9.2, swift4.1

[Apple compatibility documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Compatibility.html) is mentioning that:

> Swift 4.1, the default version of Swift that’s included in Xcode 9.2.

Yet, using Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b), the choice of Swift Language Version that I have are 3.2 and 4.0:
[image: Swift Language Version dropdown]

Is it a mistake in the documentation or a problem in Xcode? Can I use Swift 4.1 with Xcode 9.2? Will I be able to submit to AppStore using it?

Comment: I believe it's a documentation problem and that Swift 4.1 is only available using Xcode 9.3.

Comment: I report it under https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=39073035

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple documentation *was* incorrect, [Swift documentation is correct](https://swift.org/download/#releases).

Well, to be double sure of which version is supported, we'll test it:

1. Set your command-line tools to xcode 9.2 (9C40b). It will [switch to Xcode default `swift` version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204015/xcode-switching-between-swift-2-2-and-swift-3-0).

   ```
   sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
   ```
2. Test your swift version.

   ```
   swift --version
   ```

Result is:

> Apple Swift version 4.0.3 (swiftlang-900.0.74.1 clang-900.0.39.2)

In conclusion, it's really an Apple documentation issue:
**Swift 4.1 is only natively available using Xcode 9.3+**

---

#### Update: 3 months later

With the release of Xcode 10 on June 4th 2018, Apple documentation was finally correctly updated, stating that Swift 4.2 is available using Xcode 10.0+.