# How to check, swift version for Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift-playground

I was just testing my code in play ground(xcode-8.2), using swift tutorial. I came across following sample code:

[One-Sided Ranges](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60)

```
for name in names[2...] {
    print(name)
}
```

now my play ground showing an error:

[image]

now I feel that my swift version may not be supporting this code!

I looked around this answer but it provide solution for Xcode Project only.

- [How do I see which version of Swift I'm using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790188/how-do-i-see-which-version-of-swift-im-using)

How can I see swift version of play ground?

Comment: Xcode 9 - Swift 4. Xcode 8 - Swift 3.

Comment: @rmaddy - It seems, a question for me, also, Xcode 8.2 supports Swift 2.0 to 3.2 (approx). How can we ensure, playground is supporting 3.0 and not other. How can I check it.

Comment: @Krunal It's been too long since I've used Xcode 8 and I never used Swift 2. But the APIs are radically different between Swift 2 and 3. Try using any Swift 3 syntax. Better yet, get current. Use Xcode 9.2 and use Swift 4. Nobody should be using Swift 2 any more. it's history.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I also use Xcode 9.2+, a simple question is, an Xcode tools supports multiple versions of Swift language. How can we ensure, which specific version of swift languages is supported by a playground. Does it supports a latest version of that particular Xcode tool, by default?

Comment: Apple documentation is currently for Swift 4. `names[2...]` is Swift 4. Only Xcode 9.x supports Swift 4 playground. And currently, no, you can't choose: playground is only compatible with latest stable Swift version bundled with Xcode. I.e: Xcode 9.3 will have playground in Swift 4.1.

Answer (score 19):

Try to find out swift version using following code. (Here I tried this code with Playground of [Xcode 9.3 - beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-9-2-9-3-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-d/44390183#44390183)) and it's providing me correct answer.

```
#if swift(>=5.2)
print("Hello, Swift 5.2")
#elseif swift(>=5.1)
print("Hello, Swift 5.1")
#elseif swift(>=5.0)
print("Hello, Swift 5.0")
#elseif swift(>=4.1)
print("Hello, Swift 4.1")
#elseif swift(>=4.0)
print("Hello, Swift 4.0")
#elseif swift(>=3.0)
print("Hello, Swift 3.x")
#else
print("Hello, Swift 2.2")
#endif
```

[image]

> **Answer to your question:** I'm not sure but according to result of above code, I can say, Latest Swift version supported by your Xcode tool becomes a version of Playground's Swift Language.

Comment: Surprisingly this works on the iPad Playgrounds app as well

Answer (score 3):

By default Playground use the Swift version based on your Xcode version

You can check the Swift version by Xcode release here
https://swift.org/download/#releases

Comment: A small warning: [Some Apple documentation is incorrect regarding which Swift version is available for Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102875/xcode-9-2-is-not-showing-swift-4-1).

Comment: This won’t work if you’re using the Swift Playgrounds app on your iPad. Krunal’s suggestion does work though

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal run

```
swift -version
```

in all probability playgrounds will be using that version

Comment: This doesn't really help if you have multiple versions of Xcode installed.

Comment: --find swift and look at the path. Can use xcrun to point at the relevant version (if different)

Comment: Add `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` before to make sure you're running the same commandline tools as your primary Xcode.